# CodeDOM: Adding DebuggerStepThroughAttribute to property

Tags: c#, .net, properties, codedom, custom-attributes

I know how to add a DebuggerStepThroughAttribute to a method or a constructor, usually you add it to the CustomAttributes collection of a code member. But I don't see a way to do this for the setter and getter of a C# property, because neither of them provides this collection where you add the attributes. Does anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 1):

The `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute` is targetted at methods, constructors, structs and classes. It cannot be applied to fields or properties. You can, however, use [`DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggernonusercodeattribute.aspx) to achieve a similar aim.

That said, attributes can be applied to [`CodeMemberProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codememberproperty_properties.aspx). [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codememberproperty_properties.aspx) states that it inherits [`CustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypemember.customattributes.aspx) from the [`CodeTypeMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codetypemember.aspx) base class.